# Setting a navigationbar to be like the photo app

Tags: iphone

I am trying to set my navigation bar to be see through like the photos app.

What property is used to achieve this? I have tried the available properties for the navigationbar but I cant get is to work.

IS this possible to do?

I want the View behind the navigationbar to be seen when the bar is over it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using a .nib you can select the navigation bar and set the navigation bar style to "Black Translucent" in navigation bar attributes (in the inspector).

If you are adding the navigation bar programmatically you can set the style like so in your viewDidLoad:

```
 self.navigationController.navigationBar.barStyle = UIBarStyleBlackTranslucent;
```

Comment: Hi Jeff: I tried that and I never saw a difference. The reason is that my navigationbar is not ontop of my UITableView as a layer. How is the navigation bar set to be above the tableView in terms of layers, so that the tableview cells will be visible like in the photo app? thanks

Comment: If possible, you should be using a UINavigationController and setting the rootViewController to be your tableView controller. So programmatically it would looks something like:     UINavigationController *controller = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:tableViewController];

Answer (score 0):

I imagine you can just set the navigation bar's `alpha` property.

From the documentation: "The value of this property is a floating-point number in the range 0.0 to 1.0, where 0.0 represents totally transparent and 1.0 represents totally opaque."

Answer (score 0):

One way is to write your own implementation of -drawRect: method in your navigation bar subclass.

EDIT: A good tutorial: http://atastypixel.com/blog/making-uitoolbar-and-uinavigationbars-background-totally-transparent/